# what is the meaning of arguments in substring method of String class

Tags: java, string

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String str="Hello world";
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, 4));
    }
}
```

why the output is not Hello ? if the substring method's arguments indicate the starting and ending point respectively. And here strating from 0 index why does it end before index 4.i mean why been here the index 4 character not printed

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for that method?

Comment: Second parameter in the `substring` method is exclusive.

Comment: [`String.substring(int, int)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) says (in part) *The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.* Which seems pretty clear to me. Or were you asking a *philosophical* why? In which case I would answer ***why not***? Can go a bit further though, in that `str.charAt(str.length())` is illegal ... so there is at least one reason to be **exclusive** in the method.

Comment: Can you explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you about the documentation of that method? The Java developers care a great deal about their documentation, so if there is anything unclear about it, they would like to hear about it, so they can improve the documentation. That way, the next developer will not stumble across the same problem.

Comment: Elliott Frisch , I was seeking the ans that you explain

Answer (score 1):

`str.substring(0, 4)` retrieve part of the given `str` from index `0` inclusive to index `4` exclusive. Result is `Hell`.

See Java doc for `String` class: [public CharSequence subSequence(int beginIndex,                                 int endIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

Comment: Yep, this designe by Java. Index is *zero-based*, so last index is usually always exclusive.